# Why is the "Download as" menu item unavailable?

Tags: google-docs

I want to download my document as a PDF (I have done this before), but when I click on the *File* menu, the option to download is shaded in grey - I can't seem to do anything to make it turn black so I can use it.

What can I do to enable it?

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the document to completely load? I tried this, and while the pdf was loading the download option was disabled, I waited the document to completely load and the download option was enabled.

Comment: Are you using the right account to access the file?  It's possible to prevent viewers from downloading a file, so if you are using another google account (even one with access), you may not have any download options.

Comment: @LevenTech or Jesús, the combined information you are leaving in the comments could be turned into a nice answer. Would you consider posting one?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there are two common reasons that the "download" option might be greyed out:

- The document could still be loading.  In this case, wait for it to finish and then try again.
- The owner of the document could have chosen to share it, but prevent viewers from downloading it.  In this case, the only option would be to request that the owner change that setting.  (instructions [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?hl=en))